# How should I send my forms separately?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I write the blow codes and I would send my forms when I click on each forms submit button.
my question is how can I send each forms separately and indicate each result separately .because when my codes run all of the forms  will submit at the same time.
here is my codes:

```js
$("#done").click(function(e) { 
var url = 'secondpage.htm'
$.ajax({ type: "POST", url: url, data: $("#done").serialize(),
 success: function(data) { 
$('.divs').empty()

$(".divs").html(data)

  } }); e.preventDefault();
 });
```

```css
form{
 width:100px;
 border:1px solid blue;
 height:50px;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="divs">
<form>
<button id="done">done</button>
</form>
</div>
<div class="divs">
<form>
<button id="done">done</button>
</form>
</div>
<div class="divs">
<form>
<button id="done">done</button>
</form>
</div>
```

Comment: You have same multiple ids for `done`. Id should be unique for each element.

Comment: use `$(this).closest('form')` on button click to refer to the form that contains the button click... also use class instead of id for buttons

Comment: @inaz : Why are you asking similar questions multiple times? How is this different from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44340525/sending-form-via-ajax-everytime-clicked) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44341774/how-to-ajax-more-than-one-form-on-the-same-page)?

Answer (score 0):

you need a submit the from to change the button [`type="submit"`](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiD9oqWlZzUAhVBvY8KHRw2ANoQFggxMAI&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3schools.com%2Ftags%2Fatt_button_type.asp&usg=AFQjCNEQRoQJl_3tN5Rw3cgxkPPGjzKA2Q&sig2=HRCAeU8-PTICJVwFK1aFsA)

***Note***: i was added `divs` inside the form .for prevent the form removing after the ajax call

**Updated:**

```js
$("form").on('submit',function(e) {
  var url = 'secondpage.htm'
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: url,
    data: $(this).serialize(),
    success: function(data) {
      $(this).find('.divs').empty
      $(this).find('.divs').html(data)

    }
  });
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

```css
form {
  width: 100px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <form>
    <button id="done" type="submit">done</button>
    <div class="divs">
    </div>
  </form>
  
  <form>
    <button id="done" type="submit">done</button>
    <div class="divs">
    </div>
  </form>


  <form>
    <button id="done" type="submit">done</button>
    <div class="divs">
    </div>
  </form>
```

Comment: i've tried your code but non of them  not submited.

Comment: i've tried that again. but the form does not submit and does not show the content of second page in div with classname: divs

Answer (score 0):

You have many problems in your actual code, from which we can state:

- Giving the same `id` for multiple elements in the page, you can use `class` instead.
- With `$("#done").serialize()` you are only serializing the first element with `id="done"` and not any `form`.
- You are overriding the `.divs` content so deleting your forms from the page with `$('.divs').empty()` and `$(".divs").html(data)`, you better use a specific element to show the response and use `.text()` method to fill it with the content.

I tried to refactor your code so it works the way you want, here's what you will need:

```
$(".done").click(function(e) {
  var url = 'secondpage.htm';
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: url,
    data: $(this).closest('form').serialize(),
    success: function(data) {
      //$('.divs').empty() You will erase your form here
      $(this).closest('.preview').text(data)
    }
  });
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

**Demo:**

```js
$(".done").click(function(e) {
  var url = 'secondpage.htm';
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: url,
    data: $(this).closest('form').serialize(),
    success: function(data) {
      //$('.divs').empty() You will erase your form here
      $(this).closest('.preview').text(data)
    }
  });
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

```css
form {
  width: 100px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="divs">
  <form>
    <button class="done">done</button>
  </form>
  <div class="preview"></div>
</div>
<div class="divs">
  <form>
    <button class="done">done</button>
  </form>
  <div class="preview"></div>
</div>
<div class="divs">
  <form>
    <button class="done">done</button>
  </form>
  <div class="preview"></div>
</div>
```

**Note:**

- I used a `done` class instead of `id`, and referred it with
  `$('.done')` in JS code.
- I used `$(this).closest('form').serialize()` to respectively serialize the appropriate `form` when clicking on the button.
- I added a div with `class="preview"` in each form to hold the displayed response, and filled it with `$(this).closest('.preview').text(data)` in the JS code.
- By using `$(this).closest()` we are sure to handle only the form containing the clicked button.