# sending form via ajax everytime clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I want to send my forms by click on each submit button.

**My question:** How can i send each forms and indicate each result separately. I've tested the following code but it does not send any thing and there is no result in div with ‍`.divs`:

```js
$("form").on('submit',function(e) {
  var url = 'http://seller.ir/test'
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: url,
    data: $(this).serialize(),
    success: function(data) {
      $(this).find('.divs').empty
      $(this).find('.divs').html(data)

    }
  });
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

```css
form{
 width:100px;
 border:1px solid blue;
 height:50px;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="divs">
<form>
<button id="done"type="submit">done</button>
</form>
</div>
<div class="divs">
<form>
<button id="done" type="submit">done</button>
</form>
</div>
<div class="divs">
<form>
<button id="done" type="submit">done</button>
</form>
</div>
```

Comment: After ajax success ,the form was removed . for adding the `html(data)`.for Better you could add the `.divs` inside form

Comment: @prasad yes i want to remove the form and show the result of the second page instead of that

Comment: First, use the error function for debugging AJAX. Second there is a simple way to send form by ajax, give a look at this link http://malsup.com/jquery/form/#file-upload

Comment: The link i give to you is for submit images but you can submit form, the direct link for that is http://malsup.com/jquery/form/#ajaxSubmit

Comment: @inaz : Why are you asking similar questions multiple times? How is this different from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44300489/how-should-i-send-my-forms-seperately) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44341774/how-to-ajax-more-than-one-form-on-the-same-page)?

Answer (score 0):

The only problem with your code is that your forms don't have `.divs` as their descendants. Please read the documentation of [.find()](https://api.jquery.com/find/).

> Get the descendants of each element in the current set of matched elements, filtered by a selector, jQuery object, or element.

Change your HTML to

```
<form>
  <button id="done"type="submit">done</button>
  <div class="divs"></div>
</form>
<form>
  <button id="done"type="submit">done</button>
  <div class="divs"></div>
</form>
<form>
  <button id="done"type="submit">done</button>
  <div class="divs"></div>
</form>
```

Now, if you press the **done** button, the corresponding form will trigger its `submit` event, which will be handled by jQuery. Also, as other answers pointed out, IDs for different elements have to be unique for an HTML page.

If you're just replacing the contents of the inner `div`, this line is sufficient.

```
$(this).find('.divs').html(data);
```

You don't need to empty the div first.