# How to AJAX more than one form on the same page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I had a form that when I clicked on submit it was submitted. Then that form hid and the result of action page showed in div with classname=`dig`.

It was working correctly but when I added another forms it stopped working correctly and all of the forms submitted at the same time.

How can I change my code?:

```js
$(".done").click(function(e) {
  var url = 'http://seller.ir/test'
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: url,
    data: $(".formi").serialize(),
    success: function(data) {
      $('.dig').empty()

      $('.dig').html(data)
    }
  });
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

```css
.dig {
  width: 200px;
  height: 30px;
  border: 1px solid #000
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="dig">
  <form class="formi">
    <button class="done">done</button>
  </form>
</div>
<div class="dig">
  <form class="formi">
    <button class="done">done</button>
  </form>
</div>
<div class="dig">
  <form class="formi">
    <button class="done">done</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: you want to submit for at a one time only one?

Comment: @KaushikMakwana i want to send each form separately. and show the result separately too.

Comment: @inaz : Why are you asking similar questions multiple times? How is this different from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44340525/sending-form-via-ajax-everytime-clicked) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44300489/how-should-i-send-my-forms-seperately)?

Comment: @31piy cuz i didn't get a correct answer to my question :)

Comment: @inaz: In that case you need to discuss on the same question. Asking multiple questions on the same problem is not a good idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should empty and fill the corresponding `dig` element only as

```
$(".done").click(function(e) {
   var url = 'http://seller.ir/test';
   var digElement=$(this).parents('.dig');
   $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: url,
      data: $(this).parent('.formi').serialize(),
      success: function(data) {
          digElement.html(data)
      }
   });
   e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: `$(digElement).empty()` is not needed before an .html() - also digElement is a jQuery object so just   `digElement.html(data)` is needed

Answer (score 1):

```
$(".done").click(function(e) {
   var dig=$(this).parents('.dig');
  var url = 'http://seller.ir/test'
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: url,
    data: $(this).parent('.formi').serialize(),
    success: function(data) {
      $(dig).empty()

      $(dig).html(data)
    }
  });
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: change $('.dig').empty() to $('.dig').html("")

Comment: `$(dig).empty()` is not needed before an .html() - also dig is a jQuery object so just   `dig.html(data)` is needed

Answer (score 1):

Try with `form` submit and  `$(that).closest('.dig').empty()` to find the `.dig` .In this snippet is not working .Snippet blocked some ajax function call

change the button as `type="submit"`

**Note** create the ajax function is separate and call with `new ajax` like constructor .Its not disturbing  on going ajax

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 $("form").on('submit',function(e) {
   var url = 'http://seller.ir/test';
   new ajax($(this))
   e.preventDefault();
 });
 })
 
function ajax(that){
  $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: url,
      data: $(that).serialize(),
      success: function(data) {
        $(that).closest('.dig').empty()
      },
      error:function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
       console.log(textStatus)
      }
    });
}
```

```css
.dig {
  width: 200px;
  height: 30px;
  border: 1px solid #000
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="dig">
  <form class="formi">
    <button class="done" type="submit">done</button>
  </form>
</div>
<div class="dig">
  <form class="formi">
    <button class="done" type="submit">done</button>
  </form>
</div>
<div class="dig">
  <form class="formi">
    <button class="done" type="submit">done</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: You mean `$that.closest('.dig').html(data)` I think

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(".done").click(function(e) {
  var url = 'http://seller.ir/test'
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: url,
    data: $(this).parents("form").serialize(),
    success: function(data) {
      $(this).parents("dig").empty()

      $(this).parents("dig").html(data)
    }
  });
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

```css
.dig {
  width: 200px;
  height: 30px;
  border: 1px solid #000
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="dig">
  <form class="formi">
    <button class="done">done</button>
  </form>
</div>
<div class="dig">
  <form class="formi">
    <button class="done">done</button>
  </form>
</div>
<div class="dig">
  <form class="formi">
    <button class="done">done</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

Try This!And send update if it doesn't work.